# Can't find Google Play Games settings in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm following the instructions in [Google Play Games plugin for Unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) where it says `Back in Unity, open the setup dialog Window > Google Play Games > Setup... > Android Setup`.

I can't find `Google Play Games` anywhere. I'm probably missing something really obvious but can't find any information about it.

I'm using Unity5.3.2f1 Personal.

How can I access these settings?

Comment: I had it under Windows tab in Unity 5 for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow this instruction?

To download the plugin, clone this Git repository into your file system (or download it as a ZIP file and unpack it). Then, look for the unitypackage file in the current-build directory:

current-build/GooglePlayGamesPluginForUnity-X.YY.ZZ.unitypackage
To install the plugin, simply open your game project in Unity and import that file into your project's assets, as you would any other Unity package. This is accomplished through the Assets | Import Package | Custom Package menu item (you can also reach this menu it by right-clicking the Assets folder). After importing, you should see that a new menu item was added to the Window menu: "Google Play Games". If you don't see the new menu items, refresh the assets by clicking Assets | Refresh and try again.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like that is the solution. I'll try when I get home today. I wish they listed that step first instead of about 6 steps later... I guess it's obvious to anyone who uses plugins all the time (I haven't used Unity for about 5 years!)

Comment: Hi, I had a same problem... Also, Accept the answer ;)

Comment: Just wanted to make sure it worked first. All looks good, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your current build platform is set to Android. `From File > Build Settings`, select Android and click Switch Platform.

Once you do the above steps, you will get a popup saying something like "Google play games plugin has been configured". Now you can access it `window > Google play games`